# Which Google OAuth Flow is good for web application not reachable from the internet?

Tags: google-oauth

I wrote a small application which needs access to Google API with OAuth2 and which is typically run on maybe a Raspberry Pie to reduce power consumption since it needs to run pretty much 24/7. The device my application runs on is typically connected a LAN at home.

The user controls the application using a web interface from a PC/Tablet/... in the same network. However the web application is reachable from the LAN only, it cannot (and should not for security reasons) be accessed over the Internet, because it hides behind a NAT and/or a firewall.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) states that I have the following options:

#### [Web server applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)

This forces me to use a redirect URL which must be known in advance. Since my app is most likely accessed by a dynamic private IP address, there is no way I know the URL in advance.

#### [Installed applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Yes, that would work. I just need people to copy and paste the returned code into a web form of mine. However that is somewhat uncool.

#### [Client-side (JavaScript) applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)

This does not give me a refresh token which I totally need.

#### [Applications on limited-input devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices)

Polling? Well... If it works... However it requires the user to match a code shown on the device with a code displayed in the webbrowser. If I use that I can just as well ask the user to copy&paste the code returned by the installed app mode.

As far as I can see the copy&paste the code with installed app is my best chance. Is it really? Or is there is possibility to get along without that bit?

Comment: can't you use the web server flow with http://localhost as the redirect URI, and make localhost point to your application? or, if localhost isn't a possibility, use a custom domain like http://localhost.example.com/ and configure it in your network?

Comment: @ViniciusPinto: For your first idea I need a local http Server. I would not need to do anything complicated, just another redirect, but it requires to run some local software. For the second solution I would need to create an entry in the hosts table or an entry in a DNS server. Yea, all of that would be possible, but it still sounds more complicated than just "copy and past the key here". Especially if I share my app with non-technical users.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. What I see is that some companies use a public web app to coordinate communication between a consumer behind an ISP NAT and the Internet. Take a look at setting up a NAT relay, that may provide some clues...